# How to apply mouseleave in dynamic element?

Tags: jquery

PS: I'm not quietly sure what to put into title so please read.

I have table created using `div` element. This table is dynamically created as the result of server side. Inside the table, every row has `dropdown box` and they're all hidden, I want to show those `dropdown box` when:

1. the table row is hover and
2. the button inside the table row is clicked,

and when the mouse leaves the table row I want to hide the `dropdown box`.

I know it can be done using `on`, but in my case, the `dropdown box` hides only when the mouse leaves the parent of table.

here is the snippet code for the parent of table

```
<div id="table-parent">
  <!--Table will be insert here-->
</div>
```

here is the code for jquery

```
$('div#table-parent').on('mouseover','.div-table-row', function(){
    var actionButton = $(this).find('.btn-show-dropdown');
    var tableRow = this;
    $(actionButton).on('click', function () {
        $(tableRow).find('.dropdown-box').css('display', 'block');
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-box').css('display', 'none');
});
```

here is the snippet of the Table that will be inserted into `table-parent`

```
<div class="table">
<div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
    <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
    <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
....
....
....
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry haven't worked with jQuery for a while, but have you checked the live() method? it is used to add events to elements now and in the future. i.e., you can attach your mouse over and other listeners to the elements before the server sends them to you.

Comment: @Reza - using `on()` will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code in following js fiddle:

```js
$(".btn-show-dropdown").mouseover(function() {
$(this).closest('.div-table-row').find('.dropdown-box').css('display','block')
});
$(".btn-show-dropdown").mouseout(function() {
$(this).closest('.div-table-row').find('.dropdown-box').css('display','none')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
<div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
    <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
    <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind multiple events to an element. See my code maybe it can help you.

```js
$('div#table-parent').on('mouseover mouseleave click', '.div-table-row', function(event) {
  if(event.type == "mouseleave"){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-box').hide()
  }
  else{
    $(this).find('.dropdown-box').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-parent">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
      <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-table-row row-item row-item-dropdown">
      <div class="div-table-col col1">
        <p>Some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-col col2">
        <p>Some text here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-table-col col3">
        <a href="#" class="btn-show-dropdown">Click to show dropdown box</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-box" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `mouseleave()`, you're referring to the parent itself and not the element with the class of `div-table-row`.

Your JQuery should be:

```
$('div#table-parent').on('mouseover','.div-table-row', function(){
    var actionButton = $(this).find('.btn-show-dropdown');
    var tableRow = this;
    $(actionButton).on('click', function () {
        $(tableRow).find('.dropdown-box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(this).on('mouseleave', function(){ //notice that I move your mouseleave inside.
        $(this).find('.dropdown-box').css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```